# Unbound Local Error in Python for File-reading

Tags: python, scope

I have a function that reads in a data file and returns the values in that file as a list printing comments.

```
def loadcsv(filename):
    """Loads a comma-separated-value file (.csv) and returns a list of all the   numerical values, ignoring comments and any malformatted data."""
    """Function should ignore bad data, but print all comments."""
    datafile = open(filename)
    global datafile
    numbers = []
    for line in datafile:
    if line[0] == "#":
        print line
    elif line[0] != "#" or type(line[0]) != type(0) or type(line[0]) != type(0):
        print "Bad Data"
    else:
        numbers.append(line)
    datafile.close()
    return numbers
```

Not sure how I get the error given my declaration of datafile as global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `global` statement needs to be the first line in your function, so just swap the `global datafile` and `datafile = open(filename)` lines.

Comment: Great! Also, is there another way to do this w/out using global or is global completely fine in its usage here?

Comment: If this is the only code that uses `datafile`, then you can just remove the global statement and it should work the same way.